# What is the purpose of using separate {} block in a function?

Tags: java

I saw a code in a project and there was a `{ }` block inside of a method without any specifier etc.

Working code was something like this:

```
public void someMethod(params) {

    //some code1
    //some code1
    
    {
        //some code2
        //some code2
    }
    //some code3
    //some code3
}
```

As you see `some code2` is in a separate block.

What is the reason for doing this? Is it making a functional difference or just a coding standard?

Comment: What was the actual code?

Comment: You'd have to ask the author why he wrote it.  However, braces are how lexical scope is defined (a variable defined in the block goes out of scope at the closing brace), so maybe that's the reason.

Comment: I don't know about Java specifically, but it's probably a scope block.

Comment: Those create a separate scope. Variables inside it are not visible to the outer scope.